# How to start a dockerized Kafka instance and connect to it from the host machine?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

##### How do I do the following:

- Start a dockerized instance of Kafka on host `machine1`
- Run a process on `machine1` which can consume or produce Kafka messages

##### Here is what I have so far:

- I installed the following items on my host machine. (`machine1`):
- `docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin`
- This is a Linux computer running Debian 11. It exists on my local network. I am connected to it from a Windows computer via ssh.
- I added my user to the group `docker`.
- I downloaded the following YAML file to obtain a `docker-compose.yml` file:
- `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/containers/main/bitnami/kafka/docker-compose.yml > docker-compose.yml`
- That looks like this:

```
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

I don't know much about Docker at all, and my experience with it is limited, however this looks ok. I would like to use the `bitnami` containers, as I have worked with these before, albeit in a limited capacity.

I note that the port numbers look correct.

- Finally, I started the docker containers with `docker compose up -d`
- I can see the containers started with `docker ps`

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                     NAMES
b56084cdd443   bitnami/kafka:3.4       "/opt/bitnami/script…"   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp, :::9092->9092/tcp                                 kafka-kafka-1
0e6b30a47d06   bitnami/zookeeper:3.8   "/opt/bitnami/script…"   4 seconds ago   Up 3 seconds   2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, :::2181->2181/tcp, 8080/tcp   kafka-zookeeper-1
```

##### What works:

I found that I was able to create a Kafka Topic by executing a bash session inside of the Kafka container. I was also able to Produce and Consume messages using the helper utilities.

The three utilities of interest live here:

```
$ docker exec -it kafka-kafka-1 bash
I have no name!@b56084cdd443:$ cd /opt/bitnami/kafka/bin
I have no name!@b56084cdd443:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin$ ls
...
kafka-console-consumer.sh
kafka-console-producer.sh
kafka-topics.sh
```

They appear to be working. For example, I created `test-topic` with this command:

```
I have no name!@b56084cdd443:/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin$ ./kafka-topics.sh 
 \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --create --topic test-topic
```

##### What does not work:

- I was **not** able to Consume or Produce messages using `kafkacat`

This was my next stage in testing.

- I installed `kafkacat` on the host machine (`machine1`):
- `sudo apt install kafkacat`
- I ran `kafkacat` to inspect the topics: `kafkacat -L -t test-topic -p localhost:9092`

```
$ kafkacat -L -t test-topic -b localhost:9092
Metadata for test-topic (from broker -1: localhost:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at b56084cdd443:9092 (controller)
 1 topics:
  topic "test-topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
```

That seems to be ok.

I then became stuck trying to Produce messages and send them to Kafka.

```
$ kafkacat -P -b localhost:9092 -t test-topic
Hello World
%3|1680812310.642|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:b56084cdd443:9092/1001]: 
b56084cdd443:9092/1001: Failed to resolve 'b56084cdd443:9092': 
Name or service not known (after 36ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1680812311.658|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:b56084cdd443:9092/1001]: b56084cdd443:9092/1001: 
Failed to resolve 'b56084cdd443:9092': 
Name or service not known (after 15ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
^\Quit
```

At this point I reach a blocker and don't know how to proceed.

---

While trying to research the problem, I found an article which initially looked useful, but wasn't. I didn't understand it, probably because I don't have sufficient background information.

https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-docker-connection

If this article indeed does explain what is wrong, and how to fix it, then could someone explain it to me in further detail so that I can understand what to do and why this doesn't work in its current configuration?

If it turns out not to be relevant then please ignore it.

Comment: The README of the Bitnami kafka container page explains how the listeners settings can be used...

Comment: @OneCricketeer Where? https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/kafka/

Comment: On Github or Docker hub https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#accessing-apache-kafka-with-internal-and-external-clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which required some editing of my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2"

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper1
    networks:
      - "kafka_net"
    image: docker.io/bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    volumes:
      - "zookeeper_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka1
    networks:
      - "kafka_net"
    image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4
    ports:
      #- "9092:9092"
      - 29092:29092
    volumes:
      - "kafka_data:/bitnami"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://0.0.0.0:29092,INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:9092,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL_SAME_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  kafka_net:
    name: kafka_net
```

We can see this now works as expected:

```
kafkacat -L -t test-topic -b localhost:29092
Metadata for test-topic (from broker 1001: localhost:29092/1001):
 1 brokers:
  broker 1001 at localhost:29092 (controller)
 1 topics:
  topic "test-topic" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 1001, replicas: 1001, isrs: 1001
```

And more importantly...

```
$ kafkacat -P -b localhost:29092 -t test-topic
hello world
^\Quit
```

```
$ kafkacat -C -b localhost:29092 -t test-topic
Hello World
These are two test messages.
hello world
hello world
% Reached end of topic test-topic [0] at offset 4
```

Note that "hello world" is shown twice. One entry was from testing the dockerized `kafka-console-producer.sh`, the second is from `kafkacat`.

Comment: Also useful: https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-docker-connection https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/